# How to properly position elements relative to others without space

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\newcommandx{\s}[4]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \node (a) {#1};
        \node[above right = of a] (b) {#2};
        \node[right = of b] (c) {#3};
        \node[above left = of a] (c) {#4};
        \draw [brown] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
```

this is a \s{A}{B}{C}{D} symbol.

I will have more parameters, the issue is that a lot of space is added. If I remove the `= of x` parts the space is reduced but things are still not correct.

I'd like to be able to do a few things:

1. The extra space takes in to account of the passed argument.
2. The space is not excessive(as in this example, removing the = of makes it more sane looking.
3. Have the bounding box be correct and the "baseline" of the first input be that of the surrounding text so it looks like normal text inline rather than something messed up.
4. If some arguments are missing, I want them not to participate in the layout. For example, If B is not supplied, then C will "take it's place" rather than be offset of an "empty" element.
5. have some elements/parameters(not shown in the example) not participate in the bounding box. Essentially I need to "Freeze" the bounding box after some point and then anything drawn after is not going to affect the overall bounding box.

Thanks...

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

A very simple fix of this might be just to add some appropriate distances. I was not sure if the node should not be in the bounding box which you draw, or the bounding box of the picture. In the second case, use `overlay`, the corresponding macro is called `\so`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand{\s}[5][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
    minimum height=height("A")]%
        \node (a) {#2};
        \node[above right = of a] (b) {#3};
        \node[right = of b] (c) {#4};
        \node[above left = of a] (d) {#5};
        \draw [brown] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
        \node [right=1pt of c] {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\newcommand{\so}[5][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
    minimum height=height("A")]%
        \node (a) {#2};
        \node[above right = of a] (b) {#3};
        \node[right = of b] (c) {#4};
        \node[above left = of a] (d) {#5};
        \draw [brown] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
        \node [right=1pt of c,overlay] {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\begin{document}
This is a \s{A}{B}{C}{D} symbol. This is a \s{A}{}{C}{D} symbol. This is a \s[X]{A}{}{C}{D} symbol.
This is a \so[X]{A}{}{C}{D} symbol.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about using the option `on grid` to get the node distances from the center of the nodes....

Comment: I'll check it out. The main thing is the distances shouldn't be hard coded that cause collisions when larger inputs are used.

Comment: @AbstractDissonance The syntax `right of` etc. avoids collisions. Collisions may occur, however, if you use `on grid`.